# correct use of iterator to return an object from a list

Tags: c++

I have a list of meetings:

```
std::list<meeting*> meetings;
```

I want to iterate the list and return a reference to a specific meeting:

```
meeting& day::findMeeting( float StartHour )
{
std::list<meeting*>::iterator it;
for(it = meetings.begin(); it != meetings.end(); it++)
{
    if (it->getStartHour() == StartHour)
    {
        return *it;
    }
}
throw no_such_meeting_error;
}
```

i get the following errors :

1. `'getStartHour' : is not a member of 'std::_List_iterator<_Mylist>'`
2. `'return' : cannot convert from 'meeting *' to 'meeting &'`
3. `invalid return type 'meeting **' for overloaded 'operator ->'`

I'm still learning c++ so would be happy to understand what i'm doing wrong. Also,

- Is it good practice to return a reference to an object from a function ? Is there something better to do ?
- is it likely that the reference will be invalidated on some because of changes to the items in the list ?

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> I have a list of meetings.

No, you don't. You have a list of pointers to meeting. From that one misunderstanding, all of your further errors flow.

```
if (it->getStartHour() == StartHour)
```

This code would be correct if you had a list of meetings. It is wrong if you have a list of pointers to meetings. Try:

```
if ((*it)->getStartHour() == StartHour)
```

Next:

```
return *it;
```

Try:

```
return **it;
```

---

In the alternative, perhaps you really do want a "list of meetings". In that case, you would declare your list thus:

```
std::list<meeting> meetings;
```

I don't know which you want -- a list of meetings or a list of pointers to meetings. That has to do with the design of the rest of your program. I almost never keep a container full of pointers.

You might want a list of pointers, for example, if you need multiple list entries to refer to the same meeting. ("I have a meeting at 10 with Abe, at 11 with Bob and Chuck, and then again a meeting at 10 with Abe"?)

You also might want a list of pointers if copying a `meeting` is impossible or prohibitively expensive. In that case, I suggest you use a [smart pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer#shared_ptr_and_weak_ptr) rather than a naked pointer.

To answer your other question, yes, returning a reference to an object is a fine thing to do. You do need to be aware of the lifetime of that object; never access the object through its reference after it is destroyed.

Comment: Thank you (all) very much. I know that vector can change the location in memory of it's elements when resizing/removing. does it hold for lists too ?

Comment: No, it does not hold for lists. Iterators, pointers and references to items in a list remain valid until that specific item is removed from the list.

Comment: also, i am using a pointer to meeting because i want to inherit from class meeting and be able to store objects to both base and child class in the same list

Comment: That seems like a reasonable justification for using pointers. But do consider using smart pointers, to ease the burden of managing the object's lifetime.

Answer (score 6):

You have to return **it, when *it is a pointer to your object meeting*. Returning a reference is fine, but be aware of what you do with it later on. The way pointers work, is that if you edit your reference, the item in the list will also be changed, and vica versa.

Answer (score 4):

You have `std::list<meeting*>::iterator`, but your function promises to return `meeting&`.

When you say `*it` that is asking the iterator to give you what it "points to" which in this case will be a `meeting*` still. You therefore also need to dereference that to get an actual meeting, e.g.:

```
return **it;
```

Comment: I think you mean `return **it;`

Answer (score 3):

With all of the above said, I suggest you declare:

```
std::list<meeting> meetings;
```

instead of:

```
std::list<meeting*> meetings;
```

(correspondingly changing the iterator `it` to `std::list<meeting>::iterator;`), and let the `std::list` container do all the memory-related work for you, unless you specifically want to do it by yourself for some reason.

About returning a reference, the answer depends on your needs. If you want to return the entire object to the calling function, returning the reference is a good idea.

Also, consider using const-reference, `const meeting& day::findMeeting(float startHour)`, if you want the returned object to be read-only, *i.e* the calling function is able to access the object but not change it.

Answer (score 1):

More a comment than an answer, but too big to put in a comment.

As declared, the function cannot be called given a `const day&` reference.  You might consider fixing that.

If the act of modifying a `Meeting` is also a modification to the `day`, overload the function:

```
class day {
public:
  Meeting& findMeeting(float StartHour);
  const Meeting& findMeeting(float StartHour) const;
  //...
};
```

The two definitions would look mostly identical, except the second will need `const_iterator`.  Now `findMeeting` when invoked on a `const day&` will return a `const Meeting&`, or if invoked on a `day&` will still return a modifiable `Meeting`.

OR -

If modifying a `Meeting` does not modify the `day`, then just allow the function to be called either way and always return a modifiable `Meeting`:

```
class day {
public:
  Meeting& findMeeting(float StartHour) const;
  //...
};
```

OR -

If users of class `day` should not be able to modify its `Meetings` at all, do the same thing but always return a `const Meeting&`:

```
class day {
public:
  const Meeting& findMeeting(float StartHour) const;
  //...
};
```

Now only `class day` methods (and `friend`s) are allowed to modify the `Meeting`s which belong to a `day`.  You might also want another `private` method to find a modifiable meeting, but in this case it should have a different name, not be an overload.

Comment: @aschelper you can put `const` after both functions, no?

Comment: +1, I meant to point the lack of const correctness out too. You don't need them to be separate versions at all - one version can suffice, e.g. http://ideone.com/ATNGN (which is equivalent in terms of constness to this question but simpler)

Comment: @ssjeitan: overloaded functions cannot differ only by return type.

Comment: @awoodland: good point, and it depends on the desired semantics of class `day`. Edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is not directly related to your question but you should be careful when comparing floats for equality. Floating point numbers are not exact and comparing them with == is not safe.

Have a look at http://www.cygnus-software.com/papers/comparingfloats/comparingfloats.htm